# Prestashop New Fields Add in import file

Tags: php, web, prestashop

[image: I Want Add New Fields in this page Like Color, SKU]

Please help us to edit these fields. My CSV file have 2 more columns link SKU and Color. How can I add these fields in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKU is "reference" in PrestaShop as for the color, it depends how you want it, as an "Product Attribute" or as a "Product Feature". Check how product attributes and product features work and add it as per the provided examples.

Comment: and please explain what we use at place of brand and can we import color of product using csv when we import products.

Comment: If the color is "product feature" it can be imported from the "Product" (What kind of entity would you like to import?) import - there's a column Feature(Name:Value:Position), where you must add.

If the color is attribute it can be imported via "Combinations" (What kind of entity would you like to import?). 

Brand in prestashop is "Manufacturer" (from "Product" import), but before that you must import all the manufacturers from the "Manufacturer" import.